# How can I connect to a SQL Server database from within a Twilio function

Tags: sql-server, twilio, sms

When a text message comes in to my Twilio number, I would like the associated function to query my SQL Server database to be able to determine if I have a name associated with this number.

Can I connect from within the node.js code that my Twilio function is written in to an external database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to a SQL database from within a Twilio Function. I recommend you read [this blog post, which is a good example of connecting to a MySQL database from a Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/blog/connect-local-database-twilio-functions). In the blog post, the code uses the `mysql` Node package to connect to a database and send SQL commands. For SQL Server you can use the [`node-mssql` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). You could also use an ORM to make it easier to make requests.

The blog post does use the older version of Functions, I recommend Function Services, but everything else should work as described.

Comment: I thought I had searched and searched, but did not come across that article. Exactly what I needed. Thank you. It also helps knowing I can npm packages in as well.